# Creating Labels from Dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

I have a winform with a GroupBox on it and I would like to dynamically create the labels inside, at runtime. I'm using a `Dictionary<string, string>` for the `label.Name` and `label.Text`. Maybe there is a better way to do it, which I'm open to. I do get the first `label` to write out correctly, but not the other ones. Suggestions?

Here is my dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> LabelTexts = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"lblInstructions1", "Instructions 1." },
    {"lblInstructions2", "Instructions 2." },
    {"lblInstructions3", "Instructions 3." },
    {"lblInstructions4", "Instructions 4." },
    {"lblInstructions5", "Instructions 5." },
    {"lblInstructions6", "Instructions 6." },
    {"lblInstructions7", "Instructions 7." },
};
```

And here is the method I'm using:

```
private void CreateLabelsForTesting(GroupBox grpBoxInstructions)
{            
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> labels in LabelTexts)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Name = labels.Key;
        l.Text = labels.Value;                
        l.Size = new Size(130, 12);                
        l.Location = new Point(0, l.Bottom + 5);

        grpBoxInstructions.Controls.Add(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: At a first glance, it's obvious you are placing all the labels at the same location...

Comment: It looks like you give all the labels the same location so they sit on top of each other. Put a variable to hold the last top position of the last label so you can increment it each time.

Comment: You are putting all labels in the same location: `(0,5)`.  You can use a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` to layout your labels. What's your requirement?

Comment: Why the downvotes? OPs question might be obvious to other people but it is clear and gives enough code to replicate the problem. Don't downvote just because you think it's an easy question.

Comment: You may find these topics helpful: [Arranging Controls on Windows Forms Using a TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4yc3e8c(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Arranging Controls on Windows Forms Using a FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9w7ek2f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes either?

Comment: Hey, this is SO. We have downvotes and like to use them ;)

Comment: Hah, very well then! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving all of your labels the same position:

```
l.Location = new Point(0, l.Bottom + 5);
```

Instead put a variable outside of these methods to remember the last value and increment it each time:

```
private void CreateLabelsForTesting(GroupBox grpBoxInstructions)
{    
    // This will remember the last position between loops
    var lastPos = 0;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> labels in LabelTexts)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Name = labels.Key;
        l.Text = labels.Value;                
        l.Size = new Size(130, 12);                
        l.Location = new Point(0, lastPos);

        lastPos += 15; // Adds 15 to the previous value

        grpBoxInstructions.Controls.Add(l);
    }
}
```

So in first loop lastPos is equal to 0 and the label would be right at the top. You can set it to something larger than 0 if you like, this is just an example.
After the first loop lastPos is now 15 so the second label will be further down by 15 pixels. Then 30, then 45 and so on...

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense now. I was trying to go off the last label and add 5 to the bottom of it.

Comment: You could do that too, but this is probably marginally easier. I only put 15 since your labels are 12 pixels high and if you only increase the value by 5 they'll still overlap. Tweak the values to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateLabelsForTesting(GroupBox grpBoxInstructions)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> labels in LabelTexts)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Name = labels.Key;
        l.Text = labels.Value;                
        l.Size = new Size(130, 12);    

        x += 0;
        y += l.Height + 5;       

        l.Location = new Point(x, y);

        grpBoxInstructions.Controls.Add(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: @juharr It is. But if the OP wants to modify the X position then this is how they would do it.